# Unable to select the drop down value inside shadow element(webpage built by Polymar JS)

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, ui-automation

My web page built using the PolymerJS framework,I am trying to select the drop down value inside my shadow element using below code, I went to last point but the selection has not happened, I want to select any dropdown item from the screen based on text (trip.com, priceline.com etc), please help.

````
            WebElement root2 = shadowRoot1.findElement(By.id("hotels-search"));
            WebElement shadowRoot2 = expandRootElement(root2);

            WebElement root3 = shadowRoot2.findElement(By.id("detail"));
            WebElement shadowRoot3 = expandRootElement(root3);

            WebElement root4 = shadowRoot3.findElement(By.id("rates"));
            WebElement shadowRoot4 = expandRootElement(root4);
            WebElement root5 = shadowRoot4.findElement(By.tagName("hotel-rates-sort-bar"));
            WebElement shadowRoot5 = expandRootElement(root5); 
            WebElement element = shadowRoot5.findElement(By.cssSelector("#__providersDropdown > div.dropdown > div"));  
            Select select= new Select(element);
            select.selectByIndex(2);```

**My elements in the below screenshot**
[![enter image description here][1]][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/buYuq.png
````

Comment: What extension do you get (if any)? Try to click the dropdown before you find/select value.

Comment: Hi @pburgr -Thanks for response,i tried first click drop down and select no luck.
```shadowRoot5.findElement(By.cssSelector("#__providersDropdown")).click();
   WebElement element = shadowRoot5.findElement(By.cssSelector("div.dropdown"));  
   Select select= new Select(element);
   select.selectByIndex(1);```

Comment: 1. WebElement dropdown = locate the element which opens the dropdown by click 2. click the dropdown and preventively sleep for 1 second 3. locate values as child elements: ArrayList<WebElement> values = dropdown.findElements(By.xpath(".//div[@class='dropdown-item']"));

Comment: Thanks @pburgr- It's worked in this way.
``` WebElement dropdown = shadowRoot5.findElement(By.cssSelector("div.dropdown")); 
   Thread.sleep(2000);
   List<WebElement> allSuggestions = dropdown.findElements(By.xpath(".//div[@class='dropdown-item']"));      
         for (WebElement suggestion : allSuggestions)
      {
         System.out.println(suggestion.getText());
         if(suggestion.getText().equals("priceline.com"))
         {
          System.out.println("priceline available");
          suggestion.click();
          
         }

         }```

Comment: I met such dropdowns in few web apps where a select isn't select by its definition. In such cases it is usualy possible to create method which returns the dropdown items and can be used accors testcases.